# In App Purchase will not complete when testing in xcode with iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I just used a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich to add IAP to my app. In my output I see that the product is not purchased then that I am loading the product list, and then I'm prompted to confirm that I want to buy the product, and then I click buy and then it shows in the output that it is buying.. and that's it.

I will either get a pop up showing a pre-populated old ID for a previously deleted sandbox account with an empty password field. Or a pop up saying I have already purchased this in app purchase but it has not been downloaded.

I am using consumable products now. Before when I did a test app i the tutorial it was non-consumable and it all went through. However now I have tried it even with a non-consumable product and it wont complete. Additionally now my test app that used to work gets to the same point and wont complete.

Did I mess something up in itunes connect when I deleted an old sanbox account? Or what? Frustrating!

I am going around and around in circles. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Are you testing it in your device/simulator?

Comment: I am using my device. However it does the same thing in the simulator minus popping up the old sandbox email.

Comment: Herbie999, any progress on this issue? I am having the exact same problem (I too used the Wenderlich tutorial on consumables as my starting point). I have done quite a bit of googling and seen other folks have seen the scenario... it is not clear to me that it is a real issue outside of the sandbox environment (but this is just me whistling through the graveyard). Some have suggested that consumables are at the heart of the problem and should be avoided.

Comment: @Dawgless Boyd Hi, sorry, just saw this, so you've probably solved it... I commented out the code that was in place to "check for previous purchase" as it does not pertain to a consumable. Additionally you are right about the sandbox it's weird at first when you start new products, it takes some time for itunes connect to adjust and get everything in order. My first pass and a later pass with new product ID's didn't work at first as I described in my question. However after a day, and in the second case about 8 hours, it suddenly worked with no change to my code. Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Herbie999.... by the way, if you are using the tutorials VerificationController.m to validate receipts, you might be interested in a memory leak I found in the tutorial code. See the link here http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=5919&p=39196#p39196